# query snowflake with sso without external browser

Tags: single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are setting up snowflake with SSO and will not use userid and password. which is just working fine.

We have used ping Federate for SSO.
But we need to query(insert, update etc) into snowflake using python which in future will be used in ETL pipeline.

Now it seems we can programmatically use sso authenticator but again it will be prompt for Idp password.
which is not feasible in automated pipeline.

```
import snowflake.connector
# Connecting to Snowflake using SAML 2.0-compliant IdP federated authentication
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
  user='D******v',
  account='abcdf',
  authenticator='externalbrowser',
  warehouse='abcdf',
  database='abcdf',
  schema='abcdf'
)
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * from table_name limit 10"
cur.execute(sql)
print(cur.fetchall())
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I am trying to figure out programmatic way of setting up sso without passowrd prompt.
I tried to get the info but could not find any tutorial.

Any link or suggestion will help

Answer (score 1):

External OAuth works with PingFederate and there's detailed documentation:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-pingfed.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#connecting-with-oauth